# What is the meaning of “No man's sky”?

Tags: meaning

Probably some of you have heard of the video game called **No man's sky**.
To be honest, am not interested in the game, but with its title.

What is the meaning of **No man's sky**?
To which word does **No man...** refer?

Comment: Alas, your question about didactic literature and women's studies was closed. Didactic literature is writing with the purpose of instruction. This can include guides to behavior and manners and stories with obvious moral lessons. Women's studies is filters various fields of study -- literature, philosophy, history, etc -- through a feminist perspective. Since the latter often takes the stance of post-modern criticism, it's mostly impenetrable.  Likely the didactic literature would deal with gender roles, but it's hard to tell unless you know the syllabus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the expression 'no man's land' - for a piece of land that belongs to no one - 'no man's sky' means that the sky (which the player can explore in the game) **belongs to no one**.

The **man** in this case means a person and the sky belongs to no person, to no one.